# Impact of rejecting Paul’s apostleship

Tags: paul, pauline-epistles

What would be the implications of rejecting Paul as a true apostle? If we were to reject his letters, how much of a impact would that have on the Christianity we know today?

Comment: Almost half the NT would vanish and two-thirds of Christian theology would be removed.

Comment: To reject those whom Christ sends is to reject Christ himself. And to reject Christ is to reject God who sent him. _He that receiveth you receiveth me, and he that receiveth me receiveth him that sent me._ Matthew 10:40. Many do, in fact, reject Paul, and it is evident in their doctrine and in their behaviour.

Comment: you will be less likely to have this question closed if you begin with a relevant quote from the NT.

Answer (score 1):

Some in the early church did reject Paul's teaching, as he makes very clear. For example:

2 Corinthians

> If some one comes and preaches another Jesus than the one we preached,
> or if you receive a different spirit from the one you received, or if
> you accept a different gospel from the one you accepted, you submit to
> it readily enough. 5 I think that I am not in the least inferior to
> these superlative apostles.

Paul sarcastically calls his opponents "superlative apostles," but the possibility definitely exists that actual apostles (such as the "men from James" in Galatians 2) did reject Paul's version of the Gospel. Even the Letter of 2 Peter speaks of Paul's teachings as "hard to understand."

2 Peter 3:15-17

> Our beloved brother Paul wrote to you according to the wisdom given
> him, 16 speaking of this as he does in all his letters. There are some
> things in them hard to understand, which the ignorant and unstable
> twist to their own destruction, as they do the other scriptures.

But if Paul's letters were to be rejected, a very large part of the New Testament would be set aside. We would still have his speeches and deeds preserved in the Book of Acts, however. And we would also have, in the Gospels, many of Paul's teachings preserved, since his doctrine informed the gospel authors to a great degree.

The OP also asked what that implication would be of rejecting Paul as a true apostle. That is a more radical proposition, because it implies that Paul's basic teaching would be rejected not just his personal apostleship; and that teaching profoundly impacted virtually every NT author (possibly excepting John of Patmos). It would change the New Testament radically, far beyond the omission of Paul's letters.

Comment: Please don't answer blatantly off-topic questions like this!

Comment: Or if this is the kind of question that you think should be allowed, well that would be a big change to the site scope.